# JQuery on dynamically creating element and attaching data does not return value when calling data() again using selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I create a div element dynamically and associate `data()` to it. When accessing it again via selector it does not return the data. As result of below snippet I see first alert with data '1' and another with 'null' value. Can someone please help.

```
var dc = 0;
$("#attachData").click(function () {
         dc++;
  var newDiv = jQuery('#oldid').clone();
  newDiv.attr('id', 'dt'+dc);
  jQuery.data(newDiv, "dd", '1')

   alert(jQuery.data(newDiv, "dd"));

 var divFromSelector = $('#dt'+dc);
 alert(jQuery.data(divFromSelector, "dd"));
});
```

---

Sorry, I did not add it in the snippet but its attached to the tree:

```
newDiv.attr('id', 'dt'+dc).
appendTo('#workspace-container');
```

Also when I try to access it using selector the element is returned correctly - but no data found.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var dc = 0;
$("#attachData").click(function () {
     dc++;
  var newDiv = jQuery('#oldid').clone();
  newDiv.attr('id', 'dt'+dc).appendTo('#workspace-container');
  jQuery.data(newDiv[0], "dd", '1')

  alert(jQuery.data(newDiv[0], "dd"));

  var divFromSelector = $('#dt'+dc);
  alert(jQuery.data(divFromSelector[0], "dd"));
});
```

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) it seems that the `JQuery.data` method expects a DOM element, not a JQuery object. Appending `[0]` to a JQuery object gives the DOM element it is wrapping.

It'd probably be better if you used `newDiv.data(...)` and `divFromSelector.data(...)`.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/WTyg3/).

Comment: Thats a great help. I was confused since the first alert indeed return data() even when I passed a JQUery object but not the next time. This resolves my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't attached the new node in the DOM your accessing. http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: No problem, just revise your original post ... try using a lead of a new line and indent all lines 4 spaces to indicate a "code" block.

Comment: Dave - Thanks for your response. I have attached it to node. Any insight into this will help?

Comment: saw the response above from @sje397 glad you got it resolved. Please also mark the answer you accepted.